# Wiring for a bathroom, bedroom and a bathroom exhaust fan all together

Tags: wiring

I need some help with wiring plz. I live in the USA. Here are three pics of the setup i want to do.

First one is a bathroom Fan wiring. It has 2 green wires, black and grey as shown below:

[image]

The next one is for the bathroom light that was in there previously:
[image]

The last one is from a bedroom that was hooked up along with the bathroom light (yes, i know its wrong but it was setup in the 1950's and right now i dont care:
[image]

I hooked up the 3 whites together, 3 blacks together, 2 greens and 2 cooper together like it was setup as it was for the light that was previously in my bathroom. That way worked fine for bathroom had it's light switch and the bedroom had it own switch and those work fine.

Now when I hook up it the same way with all the blacks together, all whites together, all coopers and greens together and i switch the breaker back on the fan goes on when both light switches are off. The fan stays on all the time.

Can someone tell the correct setup so the fan will go on when the bathroom light switch is in the on position. Hope this makes some sense.

PPPLLLEEEAAASSEE help me. TIA

Edit: I am pretty sure there should be 2 separate junction boxes with romex cabling used throughout the house but i am pretty sure my house has knob and tube wiring and i am not about to rewire all my house since it was built in the 50's.

Edit 2: Or can I place the wires from one knob and tube cable into a junction box combined with one end of a romex cable and run the other end of the romex cable to another junction box and combine that with my second knob and tube. In first junction box hook up the black to black, white to white/gray and cooper to 2 greens together.  On the second junction box combine the blacks from romex and knob and tube, the romex white to the knob and tube white/grey and then it will work correctly? Plz let me know.

TIA

Comment: Sounds like you have a hot black on the wrong side of the switch. K&T not in the 50’s but cloth braid and your photo shows cloth.  Showing the actual connections in the boxes will be more helpful then some random wires.

Comment: without the fan involved, the connections are as followed both white are twisted together and connected with a wire nut. Both the 2 black wires and red connected together with a wire nut. and 2 ground wires connected together with a wire nut. What am I doing wrong plz?

Comment: John, just knowing the colors is not always helpful. There are things called switch loops where the switch is powered from the fixture and the white is hot, that’s why we need to see the wiring or know the cable coming from the panel it’s location, then we can figure it out, we will help but guessing at this point could cause a direct short.

Comment: Ed,Here is the pic of the wiring in my attic:    https://imgur.com/73Yim1c

Comment: Are there any bathroom *receptacles* on this circuit? Which cable or box does power enter all this at?  Are you running new cables for the switches, or...?